# Передать название таблицы,для которой создается объект класса Model в качестве параметра

Tags: c#, mvc, ado.net

Здравствуйте. Нужна ваша помощь. 
Есть проект winform,который отображает таблицу из бд на грид. В соответствии с паттерном MVC ,есть классы Model и SelectController (представление - сама форма).

```
 public SelectController(DataGridView grid, CheckedListBox clbColumns)
        {
            Model = new Model("Registr");
            Grid = grid;
            this.clbColumns = clbColumns;}
```

Здесь имя таблицы, для которой создается объект модели, жестко задано в теле конструктора класса. Как можно передавать название таблицы в качестве параметра?

Answer (score 1):

```
public SelectController(DataGridView grid, CheckedListBox clbColumns, string aTableName)
{
  Model = new Model(aTableName);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Неужели решение заключается в этом? 
Дело в том,что задание немного запутанное. Надеялась,что здесь его кто-то поймет  по-другому,может) 
Задал преподаватель без всяких объяснений.

А если название таблицы будет получено  в результате запроса?

Comment: @SoftySh Перечитайте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Как Вы думаете, сколько здесь телепатов? Какого запроса?

Comment: Извините за неточности. Это уже чисто мое предположение ,откуда может появиться название таблицы. Но видимо,это не имеет смысла.
Решение написала такое же, как у вас. Но думала, может под этим заданием подразумевается что-то другое.Видимо,нет.